# Subject verb agreement-

Tags: grammar

Are these sentences correct?

I have found this in a website.

Bananas plus water results in faster weight loss.

Laying off exercise and allowing afternoon sweets reduces stress.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ok. The complex "bananas plus water" is the subject of the verb and is taken to be singular. Similarly "laying off exercise and allowing afternoon sweets" is a concept that functions as a singular subject because BOTH things are to be done together.  If you added a second concept then you would pluralize. Like "laying around watching t.v. and maintaining an active healthy life style end with same result: death". The verb "end" takes a plural subject because the two concepts are distinct, not to be combined.